# Not able to find Nuget Installed Package in Activity Tab UIPATH

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

I’ve installed watson tone analyzer from manage package > nuget.org. and it got installed successfully. And in Project Tab > dependency section i can see it’s been added. But i’m not able to see IBM package in Activity tab but if I install any package from GO!, Official it show in Activity tab.

I tried to reinstall studio, restart studio Still not able to see packages in Activity tab.

Any suggestion?

I have attached screen shots

[dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCIqb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and download it from UI Go using the following link:

[Watson Tone Analyzer Ui Go](https://go.uipath.com/component/ibm-watson-empathy-pack-950c8a)

Additional details can be found under:

[UiPath Documents](https://integrations.uipath.com/docs/ibm-empathy-pack)

Additionally go to **Manage Packages->All Packages and install UiPath.IBMWatsonEmpathy.Activities** as per image below:

[image]

Then in your Activities Panel, look for **Integrations->IBM->Watson->Empathy->Analyze General Tone** as per image below:

[image]

Hope these information would be useful.

Comment: @Konastantinos if i install from GO! i can see it in Activity tab i.e. IBM tone analyzer but it wont support for IBM NLP and MySql.data which is nuget.org.